# Switching layout inside the recyclerview for chat application

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Hi i am developing a chat application.I have two categories **Operator** and **Visitor**. depending on this category and display the messages in left or right side like in a typical chat application.

Can some one help me to achieve this.

I tried but getting an error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem, PID: 31103
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem.Data.ChattingAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ChattingAdapter.java:66)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5822)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5855)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5091)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4967)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3568)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1735)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1579)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1488)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16636)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2179)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1939)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**current error is here**

```
if(message_type.equals("Operator")) {
            ((ViewHolder) holder).visitorMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            ((ViewHolder) holder).visitortime.setText(message.getDateTime());
        } else {
            ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorMessage.setText(message.getDateTime());
            ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
        }
```

**Adapter**

```
public class ChattingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    public List<ChattingItomObject> ChattingItem;
    private Context context;

    public ChattingAdapter(Context context, List<ChattingItomObject> items){
        this.ChattingItem = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView operatorMessage;
        public TextView operatorTime;
        public TextView visitorMessage;
        public TextView visitortime;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            operatorMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CCO_message);
            operatorTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CCo_time);

            visitorMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CCV_message);
            visitortime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CCV_time);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;

        if (viewType == 5001) {
            // self message
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_chat_operator, parent, false);
        } else if(viewType == 5002) {
            // others message
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_chat_visitor, parent, false);
        }else {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_chat_other, parent, false);
        }
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ChattingItomObject message = ChattingItem.get(position);
        String message_type = message.getMessageType().toString();

        if(message_type.equals("Operator")) {
            ((ViewHolder) holder).visitorMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
            ((ViewHolder) holder).visitortime.setText(message.getDateTime());
        } else {
            ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorMessage.setText(message.getDateTime());
            ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        String message = ChattingItem.get(position).getMessageType();
        if (message.equals("Operator")) {
            return 5001;
        } else if(message.equals("Visitor")){
            return 5002;
        }

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return ChattingItem.size(); }
}
```

**Chatting Activity**

```
public class Chatting extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String  uniqueID;
    public ChattingAdapter mAdapter;
    public List<ChattingItomObject> messageItems;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatting);


        uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Log.d("GUIID", uniqueID);

        messageItems = new ArrayList<ChattingItomObject>();
        // add some items to list to test
        messageItems.add(new ChattingItomObject("VisitorID", "Message", "10:30 pm", "OperatorType", "UserName", "Operator", uniqueID));
        messageItems.add(new ChattingItomObject("VisitorID", "Message", "10:30 pm", "OperatorType", "UserName", "Visitor", uniqueID));
        messageItems.add(new ChattingItomObject("VisitorID", "Message", "10:30 pm", "OperatorType", "UserName", "Operator", uniqueID));
        messageItems.add(new ChattingItomObject("VisitorID", "Message", "10:30 pm", "OperatorType", "UserName", "Visitor", uniqueID));
        messageItems.add(new ChattingItomObject("VisitorID", "Message", "10:30 pm", "OperatorType", "UserName", "Operator", uniqueID));
        messageItems.add(new ChattingItomObject("VisitorID", "Message", "10:30 pm", "OperatorType", "UserName", "Operator", uniqueID));
        messageItems.add(new ChattingItomObject("VisitorID", "Message", "10:30 pm", "OperatorType", "UserName", "Visitor", uniqueID));



        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_chat);
        mAdapter = new ChattingAdapter(this, messageItems);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

}
```

**activity_chatting.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="zupportdesk.desk.zupport.chatsystem.Chatting">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_chat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColorHint="#CFD8DC"
        android:textColor="#CFD8DC"
        android:hint="Write a message"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_chat_visitor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_bg2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/CCV_time"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CCV_message"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_visitor"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Android charting application xml ui design. "
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/CCV_time"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CCV_message"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_chat_operator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CCO_message"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_operator"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text=" AndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAndAnd"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_bg1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CCO_message"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10:30 PM"
        android:id="@+id/CCo_time"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CCO_message"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are assigning only one layout at a time according to message type as operator or visitor, but later you are accessing both layout's textview, therefore issue occur you need to check only one layout and it's attributes

Comment: Have you tried with `equalsIgnoreCase("")` means like `if(message_type.equalsIgnoreCase("Operator"))` ? if not then try it once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two different viewholder for each layout

```
 private final int Operator = 0, Visitor = 1;
    @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
          switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
              case Operator:
                  ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) viewHolder;
                  configureViewHolder1(vh1, position);
                  break;
              case Visitor:
                  ViewHolder2 vh2 = (ViewHolder2) viewHolder;
                  configureViewHolder2(vh2, position);
                  break;

          }
      }



    private void configureViewHolder1(ViewHolder1 vh1, int position) {
           vh1.visitorMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
           vh1.visitortime.setText(message.getDateTime());
      }

      private void configureViewHolder2(ViewHolder2 vh2,int position) {
           vh2.operatorMessage.setText(message.getDateTime());
           vh2.operatorTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
      }

    @Override
      public int getItemViewType(int position) {
 String message_type = message.getMessageType().toString();

        if(message_type.equals("Operator"))
          {
              return Operator;
          } else {
              return Visitor;
          }
          return -1;
      }
```

Comment: Can confirm this approach works. I used it just this weekend.

Comment: he is getting a null pointer exception...

Answer (score 0):

You getting null pointer due to recycling of view you have to differentiate views using `getItemViewType` like this :

```
// 5002 is for visitors 
    if(getItemViewType(position)==5002) {
                ((ViewHolder) holder).visitorMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
                ((ViewHolder) holder).visitortime.setText(message.getDateTime());
            } else {
                ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorMessage.setText(message.getDateTime());
                ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(getItemViewType != null){
if(getItemViewType(position)==5002) {
                ((ViewHolder) holder).visitorMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
                ((ViewHolder) holder).visitortime.setText(message.getDateTime());
            } else {
                ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorMessage.setText(message.getDateTime());
                ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
            }}
```

but i dont believe ur code is not working, try to clean a project

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this, when the message type is Operator you set the text of a visitor layout and ViceVersa which is not inflated on that position so android studio will return you a nullPointerException.

```
if(message_type.equals("Operator")) {
        ((ViewHolder) holder).visitorMessage.setText(message.getMessage());
        ((ViewHolder) holder).visitortime.setText(message.getDateTime());
    } else {
        ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorMessage.setText(message.getDateTime());
        ((ViewHolder) holder).operatorTime.setText(message.getDateTime());
    }
```

also on your oncreateViewHolder you defining 3 possible layout which are Operater, Visitor and Other... layout. try to use 3 identification return value on your getItemViewType() e.g. 5001, 5002, 5003 to identify each of the inflated layout.